# LINQ identity function

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

Just a little niggle about LINQ syntax. I'm flattening an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` with `SelectMany(x => x)`.

My problem is with the lambda expression `x => x`. It looks a bit ugly. Is there some static 'identity function' object that I can use instead of `x => x`? Something like `SelectMany(IdentityFunction)`?

Comment: I'll never understand why they don't include SKI combinators into c#.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Note: this answer was correct for C# 3, but at some point (C# 4? C# 5?) type inference improved so that the `IdentityFunction` method shown below *can* be used easily.

---

No, there isn't. It would have to be generic, to start with:

```
public static Func<T, T> IdentityFunction<T>()
{
    return x => x;
}
```

But then type inference wouldn't work, so you'd have to do:

```
SelectMany(Helpers.IdentityFunction<Foo>())
```

which is a lot uglier than `x => x`.

Another possibility is that you wrap this in an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>
    (this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    return source.SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

Unfortunately with generic variance the way it is, that may well fall foul of various cases in C# 3... it wouldn't be applicable to `List<List<string>>` for example. You could make it more generic:

```
public static IEnumerable<TElement> Flatten<TElement, TWrapper>
    (this IEnumerable<TWrapper> source) where TWrapper : IEnumerable<TElement>
{
    return source.SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

But again, you've then got type inference problems, I suspect...

EDIT: To respond to the comments... yes, C# 4 makes this easier. Or rather, it makes the first `Flatten` method more useful than it is in C# 3. Here's an example which works in C# 4, but doesn't work in C# 3 because the compiler can't convert from `List<List<string>>` to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>
        (this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
    {
        return source.SelectMany(x => x);
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<List<string>> strings = new List<List<string>>
        {
            new List<string> { "x", "y", "z" },
            new List<string> { "0", "1", "2" }
        };

        foreach (string x in strings.Flatten())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's given me some interesting leads too. I think I'll stay with x => x for the time being...

Comment: I tried to create a Flatten extension method too (which I called SelectMany but the goal was the same) and because of the problem with variance it wasn't really useful, I would need many overloads, so I went back to x => x...
Jon, would a Flatten extension method be easier to do in C#4 / VB10?

Comment: why did you write a function that returns a function? shouldn't all you need be a single function with a `Func<T, T>` signature that does nothing but return its input?

Comment: @Sahuagin: I didn't write a function that returns a function. I wrote a function that returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. It's not clear what you're suggesting, but maybe you should add it as an answer if you think it would be simpler than my suggestion.

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean for the identity function. You wrote `public static Func<T, T> IdentityFunction<T>()` which isn't an identity function, it's a function that returns an identity function. Was that necessary in C# 3? I have added my version as an answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be more efficient, to code the identity function: `static T Id<T> (T t) {return t;}`. Will the presented method not allocate a new function each time one calls the `IdentityFunction` method?

Comment: @CommuSoft: No - in fact, if you wrote your `Id` method and called `SelectMany(Id)`, *that* would create a new delegate on each call (due to a bit of language spec stupidity) but the code I've given will reuse the delegate every time, due to compiler optimizations.

Comment: @JonSkeet I realise this is VERY old - but is it possible that in VS2012 and newer this problem is solved - and we can directly use a static Id function (instead of your suggested generator function)? A quick performace comparion sugessted this...

Comment: @FrankB: Hmm. Not sure when that was improved, but yes, it seems okay with C# 6, anyway. Can't edit right now, but will do when I get a chance.

Answer (score 39):

Unless I misunderstand the question, the following seems to work fine for me in C# 4:

```
public static class Defines
{
   public static T Identity<T>(T pValue)
   {
      return pValue;
   }

   ...
```

You can then do the following in your example:

```
var result =
   enumerableOfEnumerables
   .SelectMany(Defines.Identity);
```

As well as use `Defines.Identity` anywhere you would use a lambda that looks like `x => x`.

Comment: I know this was a late submission, but I really feel like it answers the question better.

Answer (score 14):

With C# 6.0 and if you reference FSharp.Core you can do:

```
using static Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators
```

And then you're free to do:

```
SelectMany(Identity)
```

Comment: FSharp.Core is a big dependency to ask.  probably not worth it unless you're actually writing F#

Answer (score 9):

With C# 6.0 things are getting better. We can define the identity function in the way suggested by @Sahuagin:

```
static class Functions
{
    public static T It<T>(T item) => item;
}
```

And then use it in `SelectMany` the `using static` constructor:

```
using Functions;

...

var result = enumerableOfEnumerables.SelectMany(It);
```

I think it looks very laconic in the such way. I also find the identity function useful when building dictionaries:

```
class P
{
    P(int id, string name) // Sad. We are not getting primary constructors in C# 6.0
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = id;
    }

    int ID { get; }
    int Name { get; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new[] { new P(1, "Jack"), new P(2, "Jill"), new P(3, "Peter") };
        var dict = items.ToDictionary(x => x.ID, It);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! In your code sample you forgot to write *static* in `using static Functions`

Answer (score 3):

This may work in the way you want. I realize [Jon posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466689/linq-identity-function/1466706#1466706) a version of this solution, but he has a second type parameter which is only necessary if the resulting sequence type is different from the source sequence type.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    where T : IEnumerable<T>
{
    return source.SelectMany(item => item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get close to what you need. Instead of a regular static function, consider an [extension method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method) for your `IEnumerable<T>`, as if the identity function is of the collection, not the type (a collection can generate the identity function of its items):

```
public static Func<T, T> IdentityFunction<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
     return x => x;
}
```

with this, you don't have to specify the type again, and write:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> deepList = ... ;
var flat = deepList.SelectMany(deepList.IdentityFunction());
```

This does feel a bit abusive though, and I'd probably go with `x=>x`. Also, you cannot use it [fluently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) (in [chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)), so it will not always be useful.

Comment: You need to return `Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>` to make it work with `SelectMany`.

Comment: True, it works for `Select` but fails for `SelectMany` - it cant figure out the types. shame.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a simple class with a single static property and add as many as required down the line

```
    internal class IdentityFunction<TSource>
    {
        public static Func<TSource, TSource> Instance
        {
            get { return x => x; }
        }
    }

    SelectMany(IdentityFunction<Foo>.Instance)
```