# "Self projecting" Linq

Tags: c#, linq, select, lambda, expression

I am new to the System.Linq.Expressions namespace, but it seems you can do some pretty awesome things.

I would like to create a "self projecting" lambda expression using the System.Linq.Expressions objects. Something like:

```
 list.Select(element => element);
```

I stumbled across a sample where they build a "property projecting" lambda expression using the following snippet:

```
 //creates something like: list.Select(element => element.[propertyName])

 var parameter = Expression.Parameter(elementType, "posting");
 Expression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);

 LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(property, new[] { parameter });
```

But how I can create a self-projecting lambda?

Thanks!

Comment: The recent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466689/linq-identity-function may be of interest

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `list` is probably `IEnumerable<T>` and so will the result of `list.Select(e => e)` also be, right?

Comment: I'm trying to do this without knowing T until run time. I'm using the System.Linq.Expressions objects and reflection to invoke OrderBy dynamically.

Comment: FYI, a "self-projecting" lambda is usually called an "identity" lambda, because its output is "identical" to its input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would the following do what you require:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(elementType, "posting");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(parameter, new[] { parameter });
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Using the example above (list.Select(element => element)), it looks like "parameter" represents "element".