# Is there a C# syntax for a 'null' lambda expression? eg, calling OrderBy(x => x) without the lambda expression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ identity function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466689/linq-identity-function)

It seems wasteful to have to type `x => x` just to sort something like ints or strings... is there a quicker way?

Comment: can you show your code for this wastefully written sort?

Answer (score 4):

if you have `List<T>` you can use [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) method: `MyList.Sort()`, or for other types may be you can find similar functions.

but by `Enumerable.OrderBy` as [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) says, No there isn't anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
static void Main()
{
    var array = new[] { 3, 2, 1 };

    var result = array.OrderBy(SimpleSort);

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public static T SimpleSort<T>(T t)
{
    return t;
}
```

or create own extension:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(t => t);
    }
}
```