# Can be avoided redundancy in OrderBy query on a list of simple value types?

Tags: c#, linq

I am curious to know if there is some method which does not require a lambda operator or not even a parameter to project the elements of a simple value types list. By example in the following case:

```
var unorderedList = new List<int>{ 3, 1, 2 };
var orderedList = unorderedList.OrderBy(x => x);
```

The `x => x` looks a little redundant to me since an int does not have any members to order by, as a more complex object would have. So is there any other method (preferably in Linq) that returns an ordered list whitout taking an extra parameter?

Just something as : `var orderedList = unorderedList.Order();`

Comment: There isn't, but you can make your own :)

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you for your reply, I know I can make my own, and even it would be very simple by just wrapping the existent OrderBy one

Comment: "_since an int does not have any members_" Well, you still can do `x => Math.Sin(x)` or alike :).

Comment: @AlexD you have got a good observation, I was still wondering if this does (should) not,  have a default for the current type in the collection.

Comment: @meJustAndrew I think it should, but it does not :).

Comment: I think the LINQ designers decided that this is rare case that doesn't worth to be implemented/documented etc. because passing `x => x` is not a big deal.

Comment: More generic version of this question - [LINQ Identity function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466689/linq-identity-function). There is still no identity function in C#6 to make `OrderBy` look fancier for such cases.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thank you! After reading your comment I should try to close my question, because it's a clear duplicate. Thank you again, the other users who are searching for this should be redirected to that question!

Comment: @meJustAndrew I don't think it actually is duplicate (I would have closed it as such otherwise) - sort is special case that actually has existing option that does not involve lambda parameter unlike most other operation `Where(x => x)` or `SelectMany(x=>x)`.

Comment: `int does not have any members to order by` But it *does* have members to order by.  To name a few of its members: `ToString`, `GetType`, `GetHashCode`, etc.  And of course when using `OrderBy` you're not just limited to a member of the parameter.  You can perform *any* computation using that parameter to create a new value.  To name a few more examples, you could order on the absolute value of the number, the value of using that number to look up the index of a list at that index, getting an item with that ID, etc.

Comment: @Servy the methods which you have mentioned are not members of int, they are members of object, and int ia not an object, it is boxed to object when necesarry, as it is when calling ToString on one by example. What my question is asking for, is more a default in the cases where it exists, but of course, as stated in the duplicated question, it does not exist

Comment: @meJustAndrew They still are members of that object, even if they are inherited.  Inherited members are still members.  That it may potentially be boxed when accessing the member doesn't make it not a member, it just makes a member that is *sometimes* boxed when accessed.

Comment: @Servy I guess this is more of a conceptual talking, I still don't tend to consider int as being derived from object, I may be wrong although

Comment: @meJustAndrew `int` does in fact derive from `object`.

Comment: @Servy I know it's Int32 deriving from System.Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe own OrderBy as extension method?

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) => source.OrderBy(x => x);
```

C# 6.0 syntax used.

Answer (score 6):

If you're ok stepping out of the LINQ world, since you've got a `List<int>`, you can use the built-in `Sort` method:

```
var unorderedList = new List<int> { 3, 1, 2 };
var orderedList = new List<int>(unorderedList);
orderedList.Sort();
```

Comment: And you just modified both lists :)

Comment: @meJustAndrew Nope, just the new one. When you create the second list based on the values of the first, it creates a new list, not a reference of the first one.

Comment: Now I see the constructor call, I got confused, reading just as a simple assignment, my bad!